# Sum properties of an array of objects, conditionally

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, json

I have a JSON field where each entry is of the form

```json
[
    {date: '2021-06-28', value: 1}, 
    {date: '2021-06-27', value: 2}, 
    {date: '2021-06-26', value: 3},
...
]
```

I'm trying to sum the values of those objects lying on specific dates, e.g. for 2021-06-27 and 2021-06-28 in the above data would be 1 + 2 = 3.

I think it's something to do with `JSON_SEARCH` but I don't have much experience working with JSON fields and am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JSON_EXTRACT`

The SQL code would look something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(json_field, '$.value')) FROM table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json_field, '$.date') REGEXP '2021-06-28|2021-06-27';
```

Answer (score 1):

If every row has the same two attributes in JSON, you should consider making those into table columns (`date` and `value`).  That will make the subsequent SQL much simpler.